# Animate change of FloatingActionButton image on Android

Tags: android, animation, kotlin, android-animation

I am developing a sample app.

It has a main Floating Action Button and sub Floating Action Buttons.

When the main Fab is clicked, sub Fabs should be shown.
I solved this using ObjectAnimator.

And now, I have only one thing.

I want to change the main Fab icon image when it opened.

Simply, I can use just setImageResource api.

```
val res = if (isFabOpened) R.drawable.ic_close else R.drawable.ic_open
fabMain.setImageResource(res)
```

But I want to add transition animation for smooth change effect.

And I found "TransitionDrawable".

So I tried below code:

1. res/drawable/transition_fab_main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_add" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_close" />
</transition>
```

2. res/layout/activity_main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    ......>

    <!-- ...... -->

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fabMain"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="24dp"
            android:src="@drawable/transition_fab_main"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

3. MainActivity.kt

```
val transitionDrawable = fabMain.drawable as TransitionDrawable
if (isFabOpen) {
    transitionDrawable.reverseTransition(300)
} else {
    transitionDrawable.startTransition(300)
}
```

But it doesn't work correctly...
Start and End are ok, but in the middle of the animation wrong image is shown.

[image]

somebody help me, please?

Comment: Make sure you have set `transitionDrawable.isCrossFadeEnabled=true`

Answer (score 0):

> Not a wrong icon, It' a combination of the icons, One overlays another
>   during the transition. You could try the following -

```
val transitionDrawable = fabMain.drawable as TransitionDrawable
transitionDrawable.isCrossFadeEnabled = true
transitionDrawable.apply { if (isFabOpen) reverseTransition(200) else startTransition(0) }
```

> Be aware that `VectorDrawables` won't be cross-faded in
>   the`TransitionDrawable`, You'll need to convert them into
>   `BitmapDrawables` first. See the below code -

```
 private fun bitmapDrawableFromVector(
        context: Context,
        drawableId: Int
    ) = BitmapDrawable(context.resources, getBitmapFromVectorDrawable(context, drawableId))

    private fun getBitmapFromVectorDrawable(context: Context, drawableId: Int): Bitmap? {
        val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, drawableId)
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            drawable!!.intrinsicWidth,
            drawable.intrinsicHeight,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
        )
        val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
        drawable.draw(canvas)
        return bitmap
    }
```

Related Thread - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62442627/4694013

Thanks.